# awk: print range of fields if other field matches value

Tags: file, parsing, awk, printf

I have a file with a very old format. Here's a couple of lines of examples:

```
000000582103145338520001        2000111420040924NR19 2RG195006          0119MR<PATRICK JOSEPH ROBERT<SNOWBALL<<<<THE OLD RECTORY<LONGHAM<EAST DEREHAM<NORFOLK<<INSURANCE COMPANY OFFICIAL<BRITISH<<
000000582103015819370001        1994010119981130CR2 8SZ 194205          0096MR<PETER GEOFFREY<WARD<<<<14 SUFFIELD CLOSE<SELSDON<SOUTH CROYDON<<<EXECUTIVE DIRECTOR<ENGLISH<<
000000582203047002770001        1992012619931231N1 8HP  193401          0099<JOHN HOWARD<WEBB<<<<1 SUDELEY STREET<ISLINGTON<LONDON<<<GROUP ACTUARY - COMMERCIAL UNION<BRITISH<<
000000582103000497250003        1998070119981130TN13 1SS195207          0126MR<RICHARD ANDREW<WHITAKER<LLB DMS FCII<<<STRATHBLANE ASHGROVE ROAD<<SEVENOAKS<KENT<<COMPANY SECRETARY<BRITISH<UNITED KINGDOM<
000000781D                      00000020WALKER & ETH PORKER<
000000831D                      00000014REID AND SONS<
000000841D                      00000019A. WEST & PARTNERS<
000000861                       00130029KENTSTONE PROPERTIES LIMITED<
```

I am trying to get the characters from 41st till the end of the line if and only if the 9th character is a 1. I know that the max number of chars after char 41 is 161.

Here's my awk - which breaks (mainly tried to compose it from different code found online - not an awk expert here).

```
awk -v b=41 -v e=201 
'$9 == "1" 
BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for (i=b;i<=e;i++) 
printf "%s%s", $i, (i<e ? OFS : ORS)}' 
<(head -n1000 myfile.dat)
```

What I expect the code to output:

```
WALKER & ETH PORKER<                                                                                                                                             
REID AND SONS<                                                                                                                                                   
A. WEST & PARTNERS<                                                                                                                                              
KENTSTONE PROPERTIES LIMITED<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'substr($0,9,1) == 1{print substr($0,41)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program here.
substr($0,9,1) == 1{      ##Using substr for getting sub-string from 9th character to get only 1 character and checking condition if its value is equal to 1. If condition is TRUE then perform following.
  print substr($0,41)     ##Printing sub-string value from 41st character to till end of line(since no last limit is given so it will take complete line from 41st character).
}                         ##Closing BLOCK for condition here.
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: YES! It worked! What does `substr` do? Thank - will accept as answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: @TytireRecubans, Glad that it helped you, `substr` stands for substring function in awk I will write s a detailed version of explanation in my few mins

Comment: @TytireRecubans, I have added complete, detailed explanation of code now, kindly do let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of Ravinders post.  (gnu awk)

```
awk -v FS= '$9==1 {print substr($0,41)}' file
WALKER & ETH PORKER<
REID AND SONS<
A. WEST & PARTNERS<
KENTSTONE PROPERTIES LIMITED<
```

For help with `substr`, see:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html